# User Form Formats cell without any input

Tags: excel, vba

I have a user form that I do math on some cells that user form populates.  If there is no input from user form the cell is formatted as text so when I try to do simple math on it I get the `#Value!` error on my spreadsheet.

I have tried to format the cells in the underlying spreadsheet that accepts the user form input - did not work.  Once the User Form is opened and nothing is input the cell does not allow math to be done on it.

```
sh.Range("BL" & n + 1).Value = Me.TextBox112.Value

sh.Range("BM" & n + 1).Value = Me.TextBox113.Value
```

The above code is what I use to write to the spreadsheet.  Can I add something to this to format the cell to NUMBER even though it has no value from the User Form?

```
.NumberFormat ="0.00"
```

When I try to add Column BL to BM in excel I get the `#Value!` error if the User Form has received no input into `TextBox113` - or vice versa.

Comment: you should use the User form `TextBox112` and `TextBox113` to do all your data validation, before copying that values to `sh` worksheet

Comment: I have code that formats the values in 112 and 113 as a number with two decimal places and allows negative numbers.  That only works if the User Form gets input.  If there is input it works just fine.  Without input the format is all wrong.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: So add another validation rule that makes sure there is an input

Comment: My users are not going to want to enter zeros into 30 or 40 fields that do not relate to their purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If only empty values of the text box are causing issues, I would populate the sheet only if the text box is not empty:

```
sh.Cells.NumerFormat = "0.00" 'make sure that initially all cells are formatted as Number
If Me.TextBox112.Value <> "" Then
    sh.Range("BL" & n + 1).Value = Me.TextBox112.Value
End If
```

Comment: Some of the textbox are supposed to be empty depending on the User.  Can code be added to what I posted to format when written to the file? Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Bzltyr, I don't exactly understand what you mean. Do you mean that some users cannot fill in certain textboxes because they don't have access? If that's the case, I still don't see why you can't use an `If` statement

Comment: Thanks for looking into this for me.  On the user form there are two place to enter a dollar value. If one has a value but the other does not I cannot add them together because one is a number and the other is text or without value.  This happens over and over not in just one area.  Users put in a lot of numbers - I have 80 TextBoxes.  I want to write to the file - the spreadsheet - a number, if one is entered, but if no value is entered I want the code to format the cell to numeric anyway.  Can anything be added to the code I posted to format the cell without any input?

Comment: @Bzltyr, can you replace the empty values in columns BL:BM with 0, or they need to stay empty? You could try something like `Intersect(UsedRange, Range("BL:BM")).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Value = 0` after you moved all data from form to worksheet. Also, could you provide an example workbook with the same issue, because I can't reproduce it myself or may not be understanding what the issue is?

Comment: Would have to remain empty.